# Can directory structure change code functionality?

Tags: python, fasttext

Can the way a project directory structure is set up change the way the code functions?

Specifically I have a project where I load and use a fast text model. the file I am using is in the `src` folder while the model is in the `models` folder. These folders are on the same level in the hierarchy.

When running this line of code which escapes the src folder and enters the models folder

```
#file.py
model = fasttext.load_model('../models/lid.176.ftz')
```

The code works perfectly fine. However recently I moved main.py into a subdirectory so now it is higher up and the new line of code is

```
#file.py
model = fasttext.load_model('../../models/lid.176.ftz')
```

Now the code will not work and specifically it says

```
ValueError: ../../models/lid.176.ftz cannot be opened for loading!
```

Why would this be the case? Am I violating any best practices I am not aware of?

Any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest that you convert your paths to absolute paths with `os.paths.abspath`.  Then print out each path and you'll know just what you are telling the code to load .  My guess is that your working directory is different in the two cases.  This would tell you that if that's true.

Comment: Is there any other info with the `ValueError` (like a full stack showing the lines-of-code involved)? Are you sure you're in the working-directory you expect? (You could print it before attempting the load.) If in the 2nd case you've "moved fily.py into a subdirectory", why is there now an **extra** `..` parent-directory path-segment, going up another superdirectory, rather than a new subdirectory name in the path?

Comment: you are correct. I moved main and now that is reflected in the question. I am not certain yet but I think this was a case of not being in the working directory i expected